# regexp "match" suddenly returns nil even though the expression works?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would be thankful for any input regarding this problem.

I have a regular expression that is supposed to gather some data from a string.
The expression looks like this:

```
/\[QUOTE\=(p|c)\|(\d+)\](.*)\[\/QUOTE\]/
```

The string I am using can look like:

```
[QUOTE=c|223]ContentText[/QUOTE]
```

I used this snippet of code:

```
regexp = /\[QUOTE\=(p|c)\|(\d+)\](.*)\[\/QUOTE\]/
data = regexp.match(str)
```

where `str` is the string to get:

```
1: c , 2: 223, 3: ContentText
```

`match` only returns nil. If I run the same regexp with the same string through rubular.com I get the results I want. I also tried every way of calling `match` and it doesn't help.

Have I misunderstood the `match` function? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not getting nil running this using irb. How are you assigning the string to str? What ruby version are you using?

Comment: Running 2.0.0p195 and the string is sent in to my method by: render_quotes(c.content) .The code above is the first thing that runs in the method. (render_quotes is the name of my method.) I have been checking it in better_errors and everything is in order, except the return..

Comment: [The pattern is fine](http://rubular.com/r/8zUaTmUMOG). The simple sample code and data you gave us works on Ruby v2.1.1. We need to be able to duplicate the problem to help you.

Comment: The problem is either in a different part of your code to that shown, or when the code you have shown is given a different non-matching input. I suspect it is the former, and you are having trouble using the `data` variable after the match - could you show that code?

Comment: Would love to post more code, but the issue resolved itself.. It must have had something with my environment to do since it worked after I: cleared the database, restarted the server as well as my computer, cleared all existing data in my browser. The strange thing is that I did this before posting this question, but it didn't work, so I must have missed something.

So it didn't work and I had no idea why, now it works and I have no idea why... But I think I will leave it at that and hope the problem doesn't return.

Thanks for the help anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Can you paste the exact code? Your snippet doesn't show the assignment of `str`. Your code works for me:

```
irb(main):002:0> regexp = /\[QUOTE\=(p|c)\|(\d+)\](.*)\[\/QUOTE\]/
=> /\[QUOTE\=(p|c)\|(\d+)\](.*)\[\/QUOTE\]/ 
irb(main):003:0> str = "[QUOTE=c|223]ContentText[/QUOTE]"
=> "[QUOTE=c|223]ContentText[/QUOTE]"
irb(main):004:0> data = regexp.match(str)
=> #<MatchData "[QUOTE=c|223]ContentText[/QUOTE]" 1:"c" 2:"223" 3:"ContentText">
irb(main):005:0>
```